# DatePickerDialog buttons have a disable style

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on a ToDo list, and I include a DatePickerDialog to select the limit date but when I click on the EditText element and shows the DatePickerDialog, the Cancel and Ok buttons are showed as diabled but still you can select any of those and see the date in the EditText.

[image]

This is the code of my EditText

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dateTask"
    style="@style/text_element"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:hint="@string/date_hint"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/description" />
```

And this is the code of the DatePickerDialog

```
val date = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
        updateDate()
    }

    dateTask.setOnClickListener {
        context?.let { view ->
            DatePickerDialog(view, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show()
        }
    }
```

I was reading about the themes, but I'm not sure that there could be a problem. But here it is:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.SimpleToDo" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/baby_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/blue_grotto</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/navy_blue</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/blue_grotto</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="Theme.SimpleToDo.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="fragment_toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/navy_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="text_element">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue_grotto</item>
</style>

<style name="background_list">
    <item name="android:background">@color/baby_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.CardDemo.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="Theme.CardDemo.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your colorAccent is light blue. Try This:

Put the two options, colorAccent and android:colorAccent

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   ....
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.DialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/Dialog.Theme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">

<!-- Put the two options, colorAccent and android:colorAccent. -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: I don't understand the use of the line `<item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/Dialog.Theme</item>` but with the first and adding `<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>` in the style works for me